# AWS ECS: Will Windows Containers Ever Support AWSVPC Networking Mode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, windows-container

I don't know if the issue is one of time (i.e. it'll get added eventually) or that the Windows network stack just simply isn't able to support giving a container/task its own ip address - does anyone have any insight on this?

From my perspective, having the dedicated ip means each task can have a dedicated security group thereby providing a network level security layer between tasks (very useful in multitenant environments).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's been delayed but better late than never. AWS announced the support for awsvpc network mode with the Windows tasks on ECS EC2. The steps to get started are available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/getting-started-with-task-networking-on-amazon-ecs-with-windows-containers/).